# ios App: how to open facebook link and ensure it's opened in safari and not in native app?

Tags: ios, facebook

in my iOS App, i want to open a certain facebook page in the safari browser upon clicking a button. I do this in the app in this way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/myapp"]];
```

this works if the native facebook app is not installed on the device. But if it is, the facebook app opens instead of safari (and it shows only whatever is currently open in the app, for example the users newsfeed).

I want that in any case the url is opened in the safari browser (at least as long as it's not about jailbroken devices which tampered with the browsers).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Heyy any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately solved it by forwarding to www.fb.com instead of www.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Do this -

```
NSString *facebookUrlString = @"http://www.facebook.com/facebook";

if ([[facebookUrlString pathComponents] count] > 0) {
    if ([[facebookUrlString pathComponents][1] isEqualToString:@"www.facebook.com"]) {
        NSMutableArray *pathComponents = [[facebookUrlString pathComponents] mutableCopy];
        [pathComponents replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"facebook.com"];
        facebookUrlString = [NSString pathWithComponents:pathComponents];
    }
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookUrlString]];
```